# Get back sequence of dataframes from sapply function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Here is my code:

```
test_df <- data.frame(col_1 = seq(1,5), col_2 = seq(1,5))

test_function <- function(var_1 = NA, test_df = NA){
    test_df$col_1 <- test_df$col_1 + var_1
    return(test_df)
  }

sapply_result <-sapply(seq(7,9), test_function, test_df = test_df)
```

I expect to get 3 data frames from it, where each data frame looks like original one `test_df`, but with `col_1` incremented by element of the sequence.

Here is what I actually get back:

```
    [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
col_1 Integer,5 Integer,5 Integer,5
col_2 Integer,5 Integer,5 Integer,5
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sapply`, the default option is `simplify = TRUE` and it would do that.  Instead, we can use `lapply` to always return a `list`

```
lapply(seq(7,9), test_function, test_df = test_df)
```

Or make use of `simplify = FALSE`

```
sapply(seq(7,9), test_function, test_df = test_df, simplify = FALSE)
```